# How to print out an error message if files are missing in c

Tags: c

I have written this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *inputFiles[argc - 1];
    int i;
    char c;
    int counter = 1;
    // Enter files into an array
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
      //printf("The file in place %d is %s\n",i, argv[i]);
        inputFiles[i] = fopen(argv[i], "r");
        if ((inputFiles[i] = NULL)) {
            printf("File cannot be opened");
        }
       //printf("%p\n",inputFiles[i]);

    }


    c = fgetc(inputFiles[argc - 1]);
    while (c != EOF)
    {
       printf ("%c", c);
        c = fgetc(inputFiles[counter]);

    }

    fclose(inputFiles[argc - 1]);

    return 0;
}
```

and it does what it needs to do, but there is a bug: If I print out the content of a file, the first character of the file is duplicated, how can I fix this. Furthermore as the files are read in through command-line arguments, I would like to output an error message if one of the files cannot be found or is corrupt. How can I do this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `inputFiles[i] = NULL` => did you mean `inputFiles[i] == NULL`? I'm supposing this is a typo ...

Comment: Actually, the more I read the more I see issues in the code. You declare an array of a certain size, but then start to populate it at 1, so go beyond the array (and never use the first element of the array). `counter` is weird, since if you only specify one file it too will go beyond the array.

Comment: You say that you "would like to output an error message..." and you have `printf("File cannot be opened")` in code. This looks like an error message to me. What is wrong about it?

Comment: Aside: `c` should be an `int`, not a `char`, because the constant `EOF` is not guaranteed to be in the range `CHAR_MIN` and `CHAR_MAX`.

Comment: `fgetc(inputFiles[counter]);` ... `counter` is not incremented... Ever. You only `fclose(inputFiles[argc - 1]);` There seems to be something funny about your use of `argc - 1` and `counter` throughout the file. Double check what you intended. As is you open many files, but only read from `inputFiles[i]` and only close `inputFiles[argc-1]` (could work, just looks really tortured)

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((inputFiles[i] = NULL))
```

You are assigning NULL, not checking for NULL.

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
 if ((inputFiles[i] = NULL)) { //its assignment not comparison
            printf("File cannot be opened");
        }
```

to

```
 if ((inputFiles[i] == NULL)) {
            printf("File cannot be opened");
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, but if I change this and then try and input a file that doesn't exist, I get a segmentation fault, how can I fix this